# Untag myself from an unrelated Facebook pic: which option?

Tags: facebook

Every once in a while, a friend mistakenly tags a photo thinking it is me, whereas it is not (frequent during Halloween). Other times it seems due to a Facebook bug, I was wrongly tagged whereas I appear in the next picture.

In those cases, how to remove the tag now that the "remove tag" link is gone?
We are left with those options:

[image]

I usually use "I want to remove this tag", but it is silly that the section is called "Yes, this photo is about me" whereas the photo is actually unrelated.

QUESTION: Is there anything more appropriate (less contradicting) to do?

Comment: I think that's the best option Nicolas to be honest. You could always make a suggestion to Facebook to improve wording etc.

Comment: OK I was thinking so but wanted to be sure I was not misunderstanding something... could you create an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: A mod (not me) converted his answer to a comment, it isn't really an answer, it is more of an agreement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "remove tag" link is not gone. The position has just changed.

If you follow through with the option you will get

[image: List of tag removal options]

Of which, you choose

- the first option, if it was one of the those apps that creates mosaics.
- the second option, if your friend keeps mixing you up with someone else
- your friend is getting beyond annoying and numerous messages have no effect

The first option is by far the quickest though.

[image: Get that photo down]